# Compressing to youtube quality before editing

Tags: youtube, davinci-resolve

As my old version of Premiere Pro didn't support .mts files (files straight from my camera) I used to have a ridiculous workflow:

1. Upload the video to youtube
2. Download video as mp4
3. Make relevant edits
4. Export video
5. Upload to youtube

This seemed like a totally ridiculous workflow, so I started using DiVinci Resolve as it supported mts files.

The problem I have now is as the file is still in it's original (massive) format, it is slow to do anything and rendering takes hours.

I'm more than happy with the quality of the tiny .mp4 file that youtube returns to me so is there a way I can do the same kind of conversion with Resolve? It seems so ridiculous to upload to youtube then download, but at the moment seems to still be the most efficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use proxy videos to transcode the mts files into something usable. Here's a short tutorial to get you started:

Comment: This video demonstrates a non-standard method of using proxy files in Resolve.  It's a good method, and one that provides more control than the default, but it's worth mentioning that you can right-click on any clip in the media pool, and select "Generate Optimized Media."  As long as "Used Optimized Media" is checked in the Playback menu, Resolve will manage the files automatically, automatically use the best quality at render time, and you'll never see the panic-inducing missing media badge.  The downside is it's all or nothing, and sometimes breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I'm not using DaVinci much and didn't know that.